# Method chaining в Java - что это, и с чем его едят?

Tags: java

Объясните, как оно живет и как с ним работать?

Имеется в виду следующее явление:

```java
Strings
    .emptyToNull(sector))
    .stream()
    .map(ClientCompany::fromCompany)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: что такое чейнинг? где вы про него узнали? может быть английский термин?

Comment: ну, какую терминологию преподаватель использует, так и называю...

Comment: имеется ввиду цепочка вызовов методов одного объекта или что?

Comment: @Ra'Uko, приведите английский термин, и преподаватель по какому предмету его использует.

Comment: добавила пример кода, преподаватель по J2EE

Comment: ТС, должно быть, про это [Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Comment: @LEQADA, судя по коду да

Comment: Похоже на fluent interface - текучий интерфейс.

Comment: @Ra'Uko, не смотрите на это, как на что-то странное, тяжёлое и т.д. Занимайтесь ООП. Понимание этого придёт со временем. Не стоит на это тратить дополнительные усилия. В википедии об этом очень даже хорошо рассказывается. Прочитайте статью (ссылка в моём комментарии выше). Если не поймёте, значит рано и нужно улучшить понимание ООП.

Comment: @LEQADA, вся проблема в том, что сейчас на этом строится весь учебный процесс и я тупо не могу читать код лектора - мне не понятно ровным счетом ничего

Comment: Да там всё просто. Метод, выполнив свою работу, возвращает какой-либо объект. Естественно можно тут же вызывать метод этого возвращенного объекта. В частности можно вернуть this. Вон же в википедию ткнули. Там всё ясно как это работает.

Comment: method chaining это еще один способ писать запутанный код.

Comment: @zenden2k, Не более запутанный, чем с помощью других методов, в некоторых случаях даже менее :-)

Comment: По-моему, тут проблема не в method chaining, тут надо стримы, map и прочее объяснять.

Comment: @LEQADA оформите ответом

Comment: @pavlofff, делаю

Comment: @Ra'Uko, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 11):

Цитата из статьи Википедии [Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

> Method chainig (цепочки) - общее название синтаксиса в ООП, в котором
>   несколько методов вызываются один за другим.

Там же есть простой пример кода на Java:

> ```
> class Person {
>   private String name;
>   private int age;
>
>
>   public Person setName(String name) {
>       this.name = name;
>       return this; // Возвращаем объект
>   }
>
>   public Person setAge(int age) {
>       this.age = age;
>       return this; // Возвращаем объект
>   }
>
>   public void introduce() {
>       System.out.println("Hello, my name is " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old.");
>   }
>
>   // Использование:
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       Person person = new Person();
>       // Output: Hello, my name is Peter and I am 21 years old.
>       person.setName("Peter")
>             .setAge(21)
>             .introduce(); // Вызываем методы цепочкой (Method chaining)
>   }
> }
> ```

Вся идея в том, чтобы сделать так, чтобы методы вызывались один за другим. Для этого нужно, чтобы каждый предыдущий метод возвращал такое значение, которое нужно следующему. Как конструктор Lego.

Структуру можно делать очень разную, вплоть до вложенных(nested) классов.

Можно выделить то, что использование такого синтаксиса экономит время. Не считаю, что это стоит использовать часто. Такие классы по мере возрастания сложности становятся нечитабельными.

Это стоит использовать только тогда, когда без этого очень долго.

Answer (score 8):

В Java оно ничем не отличается от других языков программирование. Вся идея method chaining сводится к простому правилу:

> Методы должны возвращать объекты.

Это могут быть абсолютно любые объекты - как относящиеся к классу или родителям класса содержащего метод, так и нет. Просто по выходу из метода всегда возвращайте объект.

Будете применять это правило - сможете организовывать довольно приятные глазу цепочки из операций, наподобие этой:

```java
player
    .takeRevolver()
    .loadBullet()
    .rotateCylinder()
    .putToHead()
    .shoot();
```

Вместо субъективно менее приятного:

```java
Revolver revolver = new Revolver(player);
revolver.loadBullet();
revolver.rotateCylinder();
revolver.putToHead();
revolver.shoot();
```

---

Также на базе идеи method chaining'а, существует идея о fluent interface, суть которой сводится к:

> Методы должны возвращать объект, к которому они относятся.

Это позволяет создавать довольно приятные глазу программные интерфейсы "построителей", предполагающие многошаговую настройку создаваемых объектов:

```java
Car car = CarBuilder:create()
    .setEngine(new Engine(FuelType::GAZOLINE, 1.5))
    .setExterior(Colors::BLACK_MATTE)
    .setInterior(Materials::GRAY_FABRIC)
    .setAbs(new Abs(4, 4))
    .setNeon(Colors::PURPLE)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/215059/), на мой взгляд, есть хорошая статья на эту тему. Правда там рассматривается его реализация на С++, но на сколько я понимаю, этот прием применим и к java.
Так же ссылка от @LEQADA на англоязычную статью в википедии присутствует, жаль что нет на русском

Comment: Почитав статейку и комменты, вспомнил, что в паскале и даже в визул-бейсике есть оператор `with`, который позволяет сделать тот же fluent без `return this`! Любой метод вписывается во fluent! Что преподносится как откровение на самом деле - дремучая отсталость супротив бейсика:)

Comment: @banme За что я люблю хабр, так это за то что в комментариях порой больше полезной информации, порой, чем в самой статье)

Answer (score 0):

Кроме достоинств в  "method chaining" есть и недостатки.
Код не всегда будет выглядеть достаточно наглядно для понимания при иерархии наследования.
Вот пример:

```
package chain;


class A {

public A chainedMethod() {
    System.out.println("  chainedMethod() in class A");
    return this;
}
}

class B extends A {

@Override
public A chainedMethod() {
    System.out.println("  chainedMethod() in class B");
    return this;
}

public void doStuff() {
    System.out.println("  doStuff() in B");
}
}

public class D extends B {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  (new B().chainedMethod()).doStuff();// ошибка - здесь попытка вызвать метод 
 //класса A
    ((B) new B().chainedMethod()).doStuff(); // так работает
}
}
```

То есть код не будет работать без явного приведения типа. Дополнительные приведения типов сделают код трудночитаемым.