# Контейнер в методе add для фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Искал, как сохранить фрагмент, при повороте экрана и набрел на этот код:

```
    // Восстанавливаем уже созданный фрагмент
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_INSTANCE_NAME);
    // Если фрагмент не сохранен, создаем новый экземпляр
    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = new MyFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, FRAGMENT_INSTANCE_NAME).commit();
    }
```

Рылся дальше в гугле, но толком ничего не нашел: что за `R.id.container` в этой строке:

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, FRAGMENT_INSTANCE_NAME).commit();
```

От куда он взялся и что он из себя представляет?

Comment: Для сохранения состояния фрагмента используется метод [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) в самом фрагменте

Comment: О том, что из себя представляют аргументы методов всегда можно узнать в документации - [`FragmentTransaction.add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: @pavloff, а я искал в классе `Fragment manager`…

Comment: метод `beginTransaction()` класса `FragmentManager` возвращает объект класса [`FragmentTransaction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction()). Здесь действует такое явление, как [method chaining](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471329/177345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае это должен быть id `view` наследник `ViewGroup`, например `FrameLayout` куда будет добавлен фрагмент. Например ниже представлена разметка для `Activity` с `FloatActionButton`, `ToolBar` и контейнером для фрагментов, который имеет id `fragment_container`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>  

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:rippleColor="@color/color_main_dark"
        app:layout_behavior="ru.temq.temperaturka.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

Соответственно код добавления фрагмента будет выглядеть так:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, TAG).commit();
```

Comment: А если мой фрагмент лежит в `ViewPager`?

Comment: @bukashka101 ```ViewPager``` работает с адаптером, а не напрямую добавляет фрагменты.

Comment: Я знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю. Как сохранить фрагмент, если он используется для `ViewPager`?

Comment: @bukashka101 Зачем его куда-то сохранять, если этим должен заниматься адаптер.

Comment: Хм... А можно как-то сохранять через адаптер?

Comment: @bukashka101 не понимаю зачем вы хотите сохранять фрагмент, в любом случае код из вашего вопроса производит поиск добавленного в транзакцию фрагмента, а не восстанавливает сохраненный фрагмент. Если есть какие-то вопросы по "сохранению" фрагмента, то наверное лучше создать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Ладно, в любом случае, я, скорее всего, иду не в ту сторону. Лучше спрошу как сделать то, что мне нужно правильно, не изобретая велосипедов на квадратных каменных колесах...