# Подскажите как создать класс типо Picasso?

Tags: java

Подскажите как создать класс типо Picasso?

Чтобы не создавать объект класса. А сразу использовать его методы через точку.
Где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Не создавая объект можно вызывать только статические методы...

Comment: @pavel, а как называется вот такая структура? `Picasso.with().load().into();`

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть исходник, могу предположить что with() создаёт объект класса, load загружает, но почему тут нет параметров?

Comment: @pavel, они есть, я не указал просто. Как это называется в Java? дайте ссылку плиз

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сам принцип, по которому работает класс "типо" `Picasso` называется - [паттерн Builder (строитель)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), порождающий шаблон проектирования, при котором конкретный экземпляр полученного объекта может иметь разные свойства.

Когда методы вызываются через точку по несколько штук, называется [*method chainig (цепочка вызовов)*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471329/177345). Данный способ не имеет прямого отношения к паттерну `Builder` и может использоваться в любых классах, если его методы возвращают подходящие по типу значения.