# Непонятный мне синтаксис

Tags: java

Пример из учебника.

```
JFrame frame =new JFrame();

Jbatton batton = new JButton();

**frame.getContentPane().add(button);**
```

Кто вызывает метод `add()` ? Я так понимаю это метод из класса `Object`?

Равна ли ли эта строчка следующей записи?

```
с= frame.getContentPane();
c.add(button);
```

Comment: а что за учебник, если не секрет? Случаем не Шильдт - Полное руководство (или Руководство для начинающих)

Comment: Это называется [Metod chaining](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471329/177345) (цепочка методов)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В строке `frame.getContentPane().add(button);` вызывается метод `getContentPane()`, который возвращает некоторый *объект*, далее вызывается метод `add(...)` этого самого *объекта*.

> Равна ли ли эта строчка следующей записи?

Да, равносильна.

Answer (score 7):

Метод `getContentPane()` объекта `frame` (класса `JFrame`) возвращает объект класса `Container`, который в свою очередь имеет метод `add()`, если верить документации: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html

Да эквивалентна, но нужен ли будет вам в будущем объект с?

Я бы посоветовал бы подучить синтаксис java, ибо к тому моменту когда начинают использовать gui люди уже знакомы такие, на мой взгляд, банальные вещи (ничего личного, просто замечание)

Comment: Я тупо иду по учебнику, просто первый раз встретил пример где используются две точки для вызова двух методов. frame.getContentPane().add(button) Объяснений такому синтаксису в учебнике не нашел по этому спрашиваю.

Comment: @RVG я чуть выше спросил что за учебник, тут задублирую. Что за учебник такой, который приступает к gui до того как объяснены основы синтаксиса java?

Comment: Изучаем JAVA Сьерра ,Бейтс. Второе издание.