# Как происходит вызов show?

Tags: java, android

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

Как происходит вызов show ? makeText статичный метод, с ним все понятно, но как дальше вызывается show ? ведь он не статичный а объект создан не был.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471329/method-chaining-%D0%B2-java-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82

Comment: спасибо !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот метод makeText:

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

Как видите, он возвращает экземляр класса Toast, у которого потом и  вызывается метод `show()`. Как вам ответили в комментариях, это называется method chaining, на этом основаны билдеры.

Вот это:

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

Равносильно этому:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```