# Есть ли в Java 8 реализации паттерна монада?

Tags: java, java-8, функциональное-программирование

Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке Java 8 реализации паттерна монада?

Является ли класс Optional монадой?

Являются ли классы реализующие Stream(или BaseStream) монадами?

Comment: Что такое монада? [Цепочка методов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471329/208074)?

Comment: @Arhad вот этот паттерн -
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)

Comment: `Optional` реализует операции unit (`ofNullable`) и bind (`flatMap`), но [не соблюдает](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-optional-breaks-the-monad-laws-and-why-it-matters/) законы монад (monad laws) для функций, обрабатывающих или возвращающих `null`. Стримы, вроде, работают.