# Как устроена иерархия классов и методов

Tags: java, ооп, функции

Учу ООП java, возник вопрос.

```
Car asd = new Car();
asd.enter();
```

Этот пример кода можно объяснить так: "Есть класс `Car`. `asd` - экземпляр класса Car. Далее из экземпляра `asd` вызывают функцию `enter()`, которая находится в классe `Car`".

С этим все просто, но не могли бы вы объяснить на примере первого объяснения этот код:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

Недоумение вызывает то что две разные функции идут друг за другом разделенные через точку.

Comment: Первый метод возвращает результат, у полученного результата вызывается следующий метод

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471329/177345

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Method chaining в Java - что это, и с чем его едят?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471329/method-chaining-%d0%b2-java-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82)

Answer (score 6):

Все просто, это укороченная запись следующей конструкции:

```
Thread myThread=Thread.currentThread(); //статический метод возвращающий текущий тред
myThread.getName();
```