# Наполнения массива java из методов

Tags: java, массивы

Имеется три метода, которые в результате своей работы возвращают массивы типа `double`. Заполнение массива данными из одного метода выглядит у меня сейчас примерно так:

```
 Factory factory = new Factory();

 double[] temp = factory.classWithMethod().method();
```

Как в этот массив добавить данные из двух других методов, используя один оператор?

Comment: опишите свою проблему так, чтобы и другим было понятно, в чем она. *"приплести сюда два других"* никак не проясняет что именно у вас не получается

Comment: Текст после кода совсем непонятен.

Comment: Нужно в один массив записать результаты работы трех методов. Использовать при этом всего один оператор

Comment: яснее не стало ...

Comment: В вопросе есть пример записи в массив того, что возвращает один метод `method()` . В тот же массив нужно записать и то, что возвращают `method1()` и `method2()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, Вы хотите вызвать методы из класса сразу после вызова предыдущего метода. Для этого сетоды должны возвращать `this` тогда это можно будет сделать.

```
public class Factory{
    private ArrayList<Double> values;

    public Factory(){
        this.values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Factory action1(){
        this.values.add(111.0);
        return this;
    }

    public Factory action2(){
        this.values.add(222.0)
        return this;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> build(){
        return this.values;
    }
}

Factory f = new Factory();

ArrayList<Double> doubles = f.action1().action2().action1().build();
```

Я конечно в примере использовал список, а не массив, но идея должна быть понятна.

Comment: хороший вариант, помоему это называется `builder`

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov это называется: [method chaining](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471329/177345)

Comment: @Artem Konovalov Ну посмотрим, угадал ли я с тем что хотел увидеть автор вопроса или нет.

Comment: @pavlofff ну может быть)) все зависит от того какая конечная цель этих вызовов. Если сформировать только массив то скорее всего это билдер для массива если же эти методы несут какую то дополнительную нагрузку то да, method chainging

Comment: Да, это именно то, но вот бы еще заставить работать. Вот что получилось: http://progerson.ru/3051-code.html      Но при компиляции выдает ошибку "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Comment: Кроме того несколько сотен раз ругается на строку - Factory f = new Factory();