# Что происходит с программой, когда при присвоении значения переменной используется сразу несколько методов?

Tags: java, android, методы, чистый-код

Есть строки кода (никак не связанные между собой):

```
mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId); 

UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Насколько я понимаю, данные строки являются компактным вариантом присвоения значения переменной. Но, мне не всегда понятно, что именно происходит в коде, при таких записях, почему методы вызываются именно в этой последовательности. И, главное, как бы это было записано в некомпактном виде?

Comment: это метод-чейнинг называется. Хотя чистый метод-чейнинг только во втором и третьем варианте, первый просто используют аргумент, возвращаемый методом без промежуточного сохранения в переменную. Думаю [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840481/177345) будет вам полезен, там же есть ссылка и на объяснение метод-чейнинга

Comment: если совсем просто: если не происходит присвоение переменной результата работы метода, то на место вызова метода ставится то, что этот метод возвращает оператором `return`. если возвращает объект, то для него сразу можно вызвать метод возвращенного объекта или использовать его как аргумент другого метода, если примитив, то использовать только как аргумент для другого метода (первый случай).

Comment: @pavlofff, премного благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первые две строки действительно выполняют присвоение (хотя я не очень понял, почему Вы назвали его компактным).

В третьей строке нет присвоения.

Подробнее:

```
mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
```

Можно развернуть, как:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(activity);
mCrime = crimeLab.getCrime(crimeId);
```

То есть сначала на основе `Activity` конструируется объект класса `CrimeLab`, затем из этого объекта получается объект класса `Crime` через метод `getCrime`, который уже в свою очередь присваивается в переменную `mCrime`.

Теперь вторая из Ваших строк:

```
UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
```

Её можно разбить так:

```
Intent i = getIntent(); //получаем интент
Object id = i.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID); //получаем id без указания типа
UUID crimeId = (UUID) id; //приводим тип и сохраняем в crimeId
```

То есть и в первой и во второй строке действительно происходит присвоение, но, так как Вам нужен только конечный объект и не нужны промежуточные, то им (промежуточным объектам) не задаются имена, они нигде не сохраняются.

Во второй строке присвоения нет.

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Так же детальный разбор:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction(); //создать транзакцию
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); //добавить действие в транзакцию
transaction.commit(); //запустить транзакцию
```

Если переписать Вашу третью строку так, как я сделал выше, то присвоение действительно будет (и оно будет в *bytecode*). Однако, Вам нет необходимости хранить объект транзакции, Вам нужно создать её и сразу запустить.

Методы, очевидно, вызываются в порядке слева-направо и сверху-вниз. То есть Вашу третью строку, например, можно переписать ещё и так:

```
fm
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
.commit();
```

Форма записи в кратком виде является более удобной и короткой, потому (обычно) используют именно ее. При создании *bytecode* всё будет выглядеть так же, как если бы Вы написали все присвоения.

И ещё по поводу порядка вызовов методов! Из правила слева-направо, сверху-вниз есть небольшое исключение:

```
mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
```

Конкретно здесь сначала будет вызван метод `getActivity`, а уже потом `CrimeLab.get`. В действительности перед вызовом метода проверяются его параметры. Если среди них есть метод **(1)** (вместо переменной), то сначала вызовутся все методы для получения параметров, а уже потом сам метод **(1)**

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!